# Send a Voice data During A call

Tags: android

Am in the feasibility study of an app which enables an automated message like, "I'll pick up the call in a second. Please wait.” or so as the user sets, without hanging up the call. So as to enable the user to get time to pick up the call if in case he is busy and also alerts the caller to be patient till the phone gets picked up.

The problem is I want to send it as voice data. Is it possible to send without attending or hanging up the call? Is it possible to send a voice data not as MMS!!!?????

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. Sorry.

Comment: Can You explain it.. I mean why its not possible?

Comment: Call voice data is handled at a lower-level by the operating system directly. You can't get access to it.

Comment: You may be trying to make hear to other user the way we get busy tones or "the number u are trying to call is switched off right now" ???

Comment: Is it possible via SMS or a voice data as MMS?

Comment: ok not possible even I think the same but i have a different perception for it. I think it is managed by the operator...

But you can make it possible by SMS and MMS

Comment: @achu You can hang up, send a MMS/SMS with the message, and re-call after a set period of time or on user interaction.

Comment: Just receive the Intent of call and make ur app to fire up after getting this intent.. You can make it happen using Braodcast receiver

Once you will get this intent you can make your app to manage the remaining functionality in the background like wise sending some pre recorded message as MMS or SMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I suggested..

1>Pick the call intent when actually you got the call on you phone

You can find the helpful links over

[here,](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/manipulating-incoming-ougoing-calls-tutorial-for-android/)
[here](http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/)
[and here](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-handle-incoming-calls-in-android.html)

2>have some prerecorded MMS or some SMS.

3> use threads sleep method to wait for some time(the time after which you actually want to send the informatory message to the caller).

4> do your job here to send the message to the caller in the background thru ur app.